# How to disable phone mic when external mic is connected to phone

Tags: android, microphone, android-audiomanager

I am facing an issue while connecting an external mic device to my android phone.

Please find the code below I am using.

```
AudioManager localAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                localAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
                localAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

Now, issue is that both the mic of phone as well as external mic are working so, please help me out from this situation that I want only external mic to work and disable phone mic.

Please find the link of external device which I am using: http://microphonemadness.com/products/mmprampreamd.htm